# Php não lê dados do POST

Tags: php, jquery, formulário

Criei um formulário que será submetido via JQuery, mais especificamente: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/.

Bom, envio o formulário, o arquivo php é reconhecido, ele retorna as mensagens de erro e tudo mais, o problema é que não reconhece os dados recebidos via POST. Segue os códigos:

JQuery:

```
function editProfile(){
$("#edit-profile").ajaxSubmit({
    url: "/ajax/edit_user_profile.php",
    success: function(result){
        $("#result").html(result);
        if(result['error'] == false){
            $("#result").html("Salvo com sucesso!");
        }
        else{
            $("#result").html(result['msg_error']);
        }
    },
    beforeSend: function(result){
        if(result['error'] == true){
            $("#result").html(result['msg_error']);
        }
    },
    error: function(e){
        $("#result").html("Error!");
    },
    type: "POST"
});
}
```

Resumo do formulário (HTML):

```
<form id="edit-profile" method="POST">
        <!--Nome e sobrenome-->
        <label class="form">
            <b>Nome</b>
            <input type="text" class="input text" placeholder="Nome..." name="name" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $user['name'] ?>" required>
        </label>
...
```

Eu coloco o `isset($_POST)` e ele reconhece, mas o `isset($_POST['name'])`, por exemplo, ele não reconhece.

Alguém sabe o que possa estar errado? Eu fiz dois formulários com uma estrutura praticamente idêntica a essa recentemente, e foi de primeira...

Comment: Acrescente id="name" no input, pra ver

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Comment: Faz um teste, coloque id="nome" name="nome" só pra ver

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente isso

Comment: E nada tbm????/

Comment: Nada, ele reconhece que existe POST, mas não os do formulário....

Comment: provavelmente está enviando vazio..   use o console de depuração do browser.  No chrome, pressione CTRL+SHIFT+I e vá na aba Network. Procure a parte de request então poderá certificar-se quais dados estão sendo enviados..

Comment: Realmente, não está enviando os dados, como faço para resolver? Creio que seja no HTML,vou dar mais uma verificada...

Comment: Descobri, era uma coisa tão boba hahaha. O modal que abria o formulário tinha o mesmo id do form...

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

Na parte onde você está utilizando o Method="POST", teste usando em letras minusculas como method="post"

Grande abraço e espero que funcione.

Comment: Luis, obrigado pela resposta. Mas creio que não seja isso...